# Bullet in own opengl framework (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, bulletphysics

We made an opengl game for the ipad and wrote everything we need except the collision detection. So we already have the renderer, the shaders etc.

My question now is: How do I integrate bullet? I already wrote my bullet collision code in a class Physicsmanager. Our game is basically set in a cave and first person perspective.

What I did is:

-Set up a dynamicsworld.
-Read in the cave model and store vertices/indices in an indexed mesh and add that mesh to a TriangleIndexVertexArray. Then generating a trimesh shape and the rigid body for it.
-For the player I just take a sphere as dynamic rigidbody.
-Then I do a stepsimulation.

Now how can integrate this into our existing framework (no bulletcode except in physicsmanager). When/where do I call it (hence creating a phisycsmanager object in the main file).

BTW: I followed pretty much the tutorial/the instructions written in the hello world "demo". The trimesh I solved the same way as they did in the Benchmarkdemo.

Comment: `I` is always capitalized in English, when you use it to refer to yourself.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the fix. I should really proofread it better next time sorry.

Comment: hi @R6D1H2 also - it really helps if you get **correct capitalization** on things that are actually classes.  For example **btDynamicsWorld** is actually **btDynamicsWorld** - not just "dynamicsworld" heh.  it really helps if you are very careful about this sort of thing.